# How to inform back Your order is ready? how to check data in server updated?

Tags: android, authentication, httpresponse

I am developing an application with login functionality. Users can login and make request for a thing through the server. When the order gets ready I need to inform him/her back (if he/she is not logged Out) that order is ready.

I am using server and an online database. How can I reply back to the person?? the device using may change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **service** to run in the background and in the service you can keep checking for the response from the server.
When you get a response, you can easily notify to the user.

Another way to this is with the use of **AsyncTask**. this is a kind of thread that keeps running in the background and updates accordingly on its **postExecute** method.

Comment: which is best method? I am also using asynctask for making server requests.

Comment: The best method depends on your implementation...services keep running in the background, utilising the system memory...where as there is a timeout for AysncTasks.
I would suggest you to use Service for the beginning and later you can change it in other ways for better applications

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) service to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this possible from a background service!
All you need to do is :

1. Start a background service that will check again and again after a specific time that the data is updated or not!
2. If the data is ready, send the data back to the user's device and check in the service that received data is not null and show a notification that your order is received.

A good example of [Android Service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)